# Core understanding f what salesforce is

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

firstly I apologise if this is a ridiculously simple question to answer but it has been bothering me for a while.

I am trying to understand what salesforce actually is, I mean in technical terms. I have read the websites documentation and the wikipedia page but I am trying to understand what's behind all this fluffy terminology.

My understanding is that salesforce is a cloud based database which stores a very high volume of information and all salesforce apps consists of scripts that query this database and model them in different ways depending on the intended application, is this correct?

Thanks !

Comment: I flagged this for moving for you. You will get better answers on webapps.stackexchange which is geared towards Web Apps like this. A mod should be able to move it for you as you won't get many answers here on SO which is more geared towards software development questions.

Comment: In addition to webapps.stackexchange, you may also want to check out salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: can I repost the question there or is there a way to move it myself ?

Comment: @rusty009 You can repost if you like rather than waiting. I suggest salesforce.stackexchange (I didn't know it existed)

Answer (score 0):

[Software as a Service (SaaS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)

To get program you need to **download** it, **install**, **configure** and so on. If your system have a lot of users it's very hard to configure ans support single user installation.
Imagine that you improved application, new release for example. You need update every instance.

With *SaaS* model you have a shared web application, that do the same thing as old downloadable one. But it's much easier to support it, because ideally there is just one instance of it.

*Salesforce* is a company that provides its own system by SaaS model, but not only. It is also a platform for developing new applications.